# What is the "Dying Whale" sound of F-35C during pattern/terminal area operations?

Tags: f-35, touch-and-go

I live near an airbase that just recently started operating F-35s. The variant is the F-35C Lightning II of the Marine Corps.

During operations near the base there is a distinct sound that - for lack of a better description - sounds like a dying whale. The sound can be heard during a touch and go in [this video](https://youtu.be/pP7oVDwlDdc?t=167) at 2:52. It lasts for less than a second, is a "droning" sound that goes from a tenor to baritone (... really struggling to describe this...). It seems that it might be limited to the F-35C; I was not able to find any evidence of F-35B or F-35As demonstrating the same sound.

My questions are:

- What causes this sound?
- Why is it only audible during certain flight phases?
- Is it correct that this is limited to the F-35C?

Comment: sounds like some kind of brief resonance.  Compare to the sound of blowing air across the lip of a bottle.  Could be something that comes up as the engine revs through a critical RPM.  Just a SWAG though.

Comment: I second that. It’s just a resident of fact of air flowing through the inlet ducts at certain speeds.  Many fighter airplanes make similar noises when starting, the F-15, F-16, and F-18 all do it, just to name a few.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Oh, this is very common in my opinion.

I live in the approach path to runway 27 at VABB (Mumbai) airport and the newer Airbus A320NEO planes that fly here make a very similar noise but for much longer durations at a much higher amplitude. The PW1000G engines are known for these noises. It occurs during lower-speed operations and I can only hear it during landing (albeit I can't see or hear takeoffs from my house). The exact cause for the noise is low power transient combustion tone caused by pressure changes against the combustion structure. All engines can do this but the geared turbofan of the A320 and A220 have a propensity for it. I don't think PW manufacturing the F35 engines has anything to do with it. This is only limited to the low-speed parts of flight since it needs the turbines to be at a considerably slower speed to get the right resonance frequencies.

It can happen during startup too

Here's a video of this noise (A220) -

Comment: That might be correct. There is also another possibility that this may be intake howl (like on [Vulcan](https://youtu.be/w1igQoRqpBA?si=ZMtYD6V49tt3tIYG&t=36s)), which according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avro_Vulcan#:~:text=Around%2090%25%20power%2C%20the%20engines%20in%20the%20Vulcan%20would%20emit%20a%20distinctive%20%22howl%22%2Dlike%20noise%5B131%5D%20due%20to%20the%20air%20intake%20arrangement%2C%20which%20became%20an%20attraction%20at%20public%20airshows.) is due to the geometry of the inlet.

Comment: @AdityaSharma I think these are related phenomena... not sure though. Intake howl happens at around 90% throttle as written on Wikipedia, the title of this question says it's happening during terminal operations too

Comment: That 90% is specifically for the Vulcan; different intakes would certainly have different air flow rates at which they produce a howl

Comment: @AdityaSharma, yeah you are right